# How to install and load dplyr without errors?

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr, package, loading

I am currently practicing R programming through swirl package. And I am stuck at the installation steps in one of the courses with the following error.

```
| This lesson requires the ‘dplyr’ package. Would you like me to install it for
| you now?

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1

| Trying to install package ‘dplyr’ now...
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

| Could not install package ‘dplyr’!

  |                                                                            
  |                                                                      |   0%Error in seq.default(0, 1, length.out = nrow(e$les)) : 
  argument 'length.out' must be of length 1

| Leaving swirl now. Type swirl() to resume.
```

Even if I try to install it manually and it succeeds I am unable to load it because of following error.

```
> library(dplyr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required
```

I have tried to remove, reinstall and update the packages. Nothing seems to work. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Or go back and first do

```
install.pacakges("rlang")
```

and *then* install `dplyr`.

Welcome to Package Hell.  Here is your banjo.  Last night I had to install packages 4 levels deep before I could get all of `tidyverse` to load.  It's tedious but do-able.

https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=welcome+to+hell.+here%27s+your+banjo&client=firefox-b-1-e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2wMPGosnpAhWSIDQIHX7JBC0QsAR6BAgIEAE&biw=1600&bih=805#imgrc=mlE1KJg7CKY-5M

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is uninstalling the Package

```
remove.packages(“dplyr”)
```

then re-installing the entire package

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Also check out pacman package
The package includes tools for conveniently controlling R add-on packages.
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pacman-package-in-r/][1]

```
p_load(ggplot2, dplyr, stringr)
```

it might save you some lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. If you are running RStudio close it;
2. open a command window or terminal window and run

```
R -q -e "install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE)"
```